# Firebase Token verification security

Tags: firebase, delphi, firebase-authentication, jwt

i'm using JWT on Delphi back-end to verify Firebase ID tokens

- all Header and Payload values are OK
- verified the Signature with Google Public-key

is that enough to verify and avoid token manipulation or i should do something with the Private-Key ?

Comment: This is solved here https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D/blob/master/Source/FB4D.OAuth.pas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the private key to *mint* an ID token, but not to verify an ID token. All that is needed for that is the public key, and some project configuration values.

Verifying ID tokens is described in the Firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library. If you've taken those steps, you can be sure the token belongs to the user and project it claims to be.